# What is the Difference Between the integer and reg Variable Types in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, vivado

After using Verilog for a few months, I am curious what the **difference** is between the following:

```
reg [31:0] sum; 
integer sum;
```

Since the integer is just a 32-bit value **why can't you just use reg to represent it?** Why might one be more efficient than the other in terms of **memory usage or access time**? Please let me know what you think or if you need me to expand on my question.

**Example Using Integer:**

```
integer t = 0;

always @(posedge clk) begin  
    if (t < 9999) t = t + 1; 
    else t = 0;
end
```

**Example Using Reg:**

```
reg[13:0] t = 14'b0; //Represent up to 16383

always @(posedge clk) begin  
    if (t < 9999) t = t + 14'b00000000000001;
    else t = 14'b0;
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
integer sum; // is equivalent to 
reg signed [31:0] sum;
```

At Verilog's inception in the 1980s, `integer` was a signed, unsized 4-state integral type. Its physical size was inferred from the simulation host tool. Synthesis tools were to infer its size from the context is was used (i.e. a `for` loop that would eventually get unrolled into a set of constant values).

But later versions of Verilog, and now SystemVerilog simply use `integer` as a 4-state signed type with a pre-defined 32-bit width. Realize that a 4-state 32-bit type actually takes up 64-bits to. hold its value.

Also note that SystemVerilog renames the `reg` keyword to `logic` because this datatype was never meant for describing ***reg**isters* exclusively. Also see: https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2013/05/03/wire-vs-reg/