# Compilation error in Quartus for Verilog language

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, quartus

I am new to Verilog and it's tools. I am simulating/compiling in Quartus Prime. In this particular code, it's showing up an error which is supposed to be the syntax of the language.

[image: Error Message Screenshot]

Code :

```
module conditional_op();
    int result;
    int a = 9;
    int b = 31;
    reg c = 0;
    
    initial begin
    
        #1; result = (a == 9) ? 1:0;
        $display("result=%0d",result);
        
        #1; result = ((a+b) == 40) ? 1:0;
        $display("result=%0d",result);
        
        #1; result = (b == 30) ? 678 : -99;
        $display("result=%0d",result);
        
        #1; c = (b ==31)? 1'bz : 1'b0;
        $display("c=%b",c);
    
    end
endmodule
```

I tried by relocating all the inputs and outputs beside the module name in the parenthesis, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code compiles without errors and simulates as expected on multiple simulators on [EDA playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/ud6P).  Here is an example simulation output:

```
# result=1
# result=1
# result=-99
# c=z
```

Since you used the `int` keyword, it is necessary to enable SystemVerilog features in your tool.  Refer to the Quartus documentation for doing so.  `int` is a data type that was added to the SystemVerilog extension to the language (IEEE Std 1800).  `int` was not part of the superseded Verilog IEEE Std 1364.

If that still yields compile errors, there may be a bug in the version of the tool you are using.  In that case, contact the vendor for support.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `integer`, not `int`. Replace the int with `integer`.

```
module conditional_op();
    integer result;
    integer a = 9;
    integer b = 31;
    reg c = 0;
    
    initial begin
    
        #1; result = (a == 9) ? 1:0;
        $display("result=%0d",result);
        
        #1; result = ((a+b) == 40) ? 1:0;
        $display("result=%0d",result);
        
        #1; result = (b == 30) ? 678 : -99;
        $display("result=%0d",result);
        
        #1; c = (b ==31)? 1'bz : 1'b0;
        $display("c=%b",c);
    
    end
endmodule
```

`int` data type is most oftenly confused with `integer` data type. This is why it is also a commonly asked question in interviews.
Here are details about `int`

1. `int` is available only in system Verilog.
2. `int` is 32-bit variable which is made of of bit data type
3. Can store only 2-state values (0, 1)
4. This is not synthesizable

Here are details about `integer`

1. Available in both Verilog and System Verilog
2. `int` is a 32-bit variable which is made of `reg` data type
3. Can store 4-state values (0, 1, z, x)
4. This is synthesizable as it represents register of 32 flip-flops.

Link: [Int vs Integer details](https://www.theoctetinstitute.com/content/sv/data-type-intro/#:%7E:text=An%20int%20is%20similar%20to,is%20a%204%2Dstate%20variable.)

Also check this thread where difference between `reg` and `integer` is clarified. [integer vs reg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61312493/what-is-the-difference-between-the-integer-and-reg-variable-types-in-verilog)

Comment: Yeah, it worked. but, what is the difference between them? Since, int is also a datatype right?

Comment: `int` is not supported in verilog.  In system verilog, `interger` is a 4 state data type (1, 0, z, x) while `int` is a two state data type (1, 0). So, `integer` data type has better coverage.